# Django {{ forloop.counter }} Target Second Object

Tags: python, django, for-loop, counter

Why does this:

```
{% if forlooop.counter == 2 %} 
   second thing 
{% else %} 
   first thing
{% endif %}
```

Always show `first thing`, even in when there are three objects in the `forloop`?

Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: `forlooop` or `forloop`?

Comment: No one is perfect. Thanks for the extra pair of eyes

Comment: Really? Two downvotes? None of you make mistakes i take it?

Comment: don't take it personally. Your question doesn't add any value to the site. It should be closed for being just a typo error. The problem is solved. That's what matters.

Comment: True. Thanks for the help in either case!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you add another 'o' in forloop, it should be

```
{% if forloop.counter == 2 %}
```